# Why are this Inputs sharing the same value?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-props, use-state, textinput

I have this Input component

```js
const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    props.setValue(text);
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

I use it in this code, there are two different views that can be rendered, but the value of one input gets shared with the other, when i write something in one and change to the other view, the same thing i wrote appears in this input.

```js
const [emailScreen, setEmailScreen] = useState(false);

const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [lastNames, setLastNames] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
```

```js
{ !emailScreen ? (
                // But for example in this view where there are two inputs, tha value
                // doesn't get shared between them.

                <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
                    // It only shares the same thing this one
                    <Input
                        setValue={(value) => {
                            setName(value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <Input
                        setValue={(value) => {
                            setLastNames(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            ) : (
                <View>
                    // With this one
                    <Input                        
                        setValue={(value) => {
                            setEmail(value);
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
)}
```

Here is the full code :

https://codeshare.io/3ApDzv

https://codeshare.io/j0ve7P

Comment: None of your Inputs are controlled, so they all manage their own state. I imaging your problem has to do with all the conditional rendering and not with the state management. Ie, you're not sure which Input you're actually looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @windowsill said, your inputs are not controlled.

Please add the [value prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#value) to your text inputs.

For your Input:

```
const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    props.setValue(text);
                }}
                value={props.value} // <- add value prop here
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

For the instances of your Input components:

```
{ !emailScreen ? (
  <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
      // It only shares the same thing this one
      <Input
          value={name} // <- add here
          setValue={(value) => {
              setName(value);
          }}
      />
      <Input
          value={lastName} // <- add here
          setValue={(value) => {
              setLastNames(value);
          }}
      />
  </View>
) : (
  <View>
      // With this one
      <Input                        
          setValue={(value) => {
              setEmail(value);
          }}
          value={email} // <- add here
      />
  </View>
)}
```